# replace number with correct number of digits in r

Tags: regex, r, character, gsub

In R I have following vector and I'm trying to get following result:

```
vec <- c("6-9 h", "9-13 h", "13-16 h", "16-18 h")
res <- c("06:00-09:00", "09:00-13:00", "13:00-16:00", "16:00-18:00")
```

My approach using the gsub function works partially

```
gsub("(.*)-(.*) (.*)", "\\1:00-\\2:00", vec)
# result:
"6:00-9:00"   "9:00-13:00"  "13:00-16:00" "16:00-18:00"
```

Now my question: Is there a way to input the zeros for single digit numbers with regexpression?

Comment: You could use `sprintf` ie. `library(stringr); sapply(str_extract_all(vec, '\\d+'), function(x) {x1 <- as.numeric(x); sprintf('%02d:00-%02d:00', x1[1], x1[2])})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use one more gsub function.

```
> vec <- c("6-9 h", "9-13 h", "13-16 h", "16-18 h")
> m <- gsub("(.*)-(.*) (.*)", "\\1:00-\\2:00", vec)
> gsub("\\b(\\d):", "0\\1:", m)
[1] "06:00-09:00" "09:00-13:00" "13:00-16:00" "16:00-18:00"
```

`\\b(\\d):` matches the number which has exactly one digit. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `sprintf` approach:

```
sapply(regmatches(vec, gregexpr("\\d+", vec)), function(x) { 
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  sprintf("%02d:00-%02d:00", x[1], x[2])
}) 
# [1] "06:00-09:00" "09:00-13:00" "13:00-16:00" "16:00-18:00"
```